# Constructing a default HashMap when the key type is unknown

Tags: rust

I want to have a struct which has a generic parameter that is used as the key type of a `HashMap` which is a member variable. I also want my struct to implement `Default` and have the `HashMap` default to being empty. But this doesn't compile:

```
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Default)]
struct X<T: Hash + Eq> {
    x: HashMap<T, String>
}

impl<T: Hash + Eq> X<T> {
    fn new() -> X<T> {
        Default::default()
    }
}

fn main() {

}
```

It says:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: std::default::Default` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:11:9
   |
11 |         Default::default()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::default::Default` is not implemented for `T`
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where T: std::default::Default` bound
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::default::Default` for `X<T>`
   = note: required by `std::default::Default::default`
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: This is because `#[derive]` uses incorrect bounds. You will need to implement `Default` manually.

Comment: I have this same question, but I don't think the linked answer is a relevant answer, or if it is, I don't see how. This question is specifically about HashMap. `HashMap<K, V>` does not have a `Default` type bound for `K`. The comment above is an answer, but I don't think that this question should be closed as a duplicate.